# Local splitting of modular Galois representations as $p$ varies

Tags: modular-forms, galois-representations

If $f$ is a classical eigenform of weight $\geq 2$ and ordinary at distinct, odd primes $p$ and $q$ which do not divide the level is it true that the restriction (as a $q$-adic representation) $\rho_{f,q}|G_q$ splits (i.e.is diagonal w.r.t some basis) iff $\rho_{f,p}|G_p$, considered as a $p$-adic representation, splits?

One expects this to be true from the  application of the "splitting implies CM" conjecture followed by its converse (which is well-known to be true) but is there a direct way of seeing this result...via compatible systems maybe? Thanks.

Comment: Your proposed equivalence obviously amounts to one implication, and this is expected by the reason that you say, and in fact, by an application of Cebotarev (I believe) *equivalent* to the "splitting implies CM" conjecture. So the answer to your question would be: it is expected that to be so (i.e. true), but apparently no one knows yet how to prove it in general. 

Comment: Thanks monodromy. Could you possibly expand on the equivalence using Cebotarev (a reference perhaps?)

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't heard of this "split implies CM" conjecture. Is there some reference to this? Maybe a name?

Comment: @Dror: I've seen this conjecture in papers of Pollack and Stevens on p-adic modular symbols; I don't know if that's where it first originated.

Comment: The conjecture is attributed to Ralph Greenberg although Eknath Ghate and Nike Vatsal have done the most work on it. One can find 3 or 4 papers on work related to this problem on Ghate's page. Emerton has quite a famous preprint "A p-adic variational Hodge conjecture and modular forms with complex multiplication" where he shows how this conjecture follows from the conjecture in the title of the paper. 

Comment: Here is a nice exposition of Ghate's results: http://www-ma2.upc.edu/vrotger/docs/students/FCastella.pdf